# ¿Cómo dar movimiento a una forma con Javascript y CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, animación

Buenas noches estoy tratando de dar animación (que se mueva en su mismo sitio, solo ROTACIÓN no traslación)  a un circulo con `javascript` y `css` pero no tengo idea. Hasta ahora solo tengo la esfera. solo falta darle la animación.

A continuación el el `código`, agradezco su apoyo.

```css
.ball {
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 50px auto 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
}



.b1 {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%, white 1px, aqua 3%, darkblue 60%, aqua 100%);  
}
```

```html
<div class="ball b1"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el movimiento que deseas?

Comment: Movimiento circular, desde el punto centro.

Answer (score 6):

```css
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.init {
  top: 45%;
  left: 44%;
}

.b1 {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%, white 1px, aqua 3%, darkblue 60%, aqua 100%);
}

#box:hover .move-right {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  /** Opera **/
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  /** Firefox **/
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  /** Firefox **/
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  /** Opera **/
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="one">
  <div class="ball init b1 move-right"></div>
</div>
```

Con `transform: translate(250px, 0)` mueves un objeto mediante las coordenadas del plano cartesiano (x,y) y (-x,-y) y `transition` realizas la transición del elemento que deseas.

Comment: Esta excelente, pero que se mueva en su mismo sitio, solo ROTACIÓN no traslación.

Comment: Edite la respuesta, utiliza `transform: rotate(360deg)` de acuerdo a lo que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

- Puedes hacerlo a través de `keyframes` para establecer los estados de la animación a través de porcentajes de avance
- Posterior en las propiedades de la animación usa `animation-iteration-count` con un valor de `infinite` para que el giro no se detenga
- Usa la propiedad `animation-duration` con 1s de tiempo para indicar cuanto tiempo le va a tomar a la animación completar un ciclo es decir que vaya desde el 0% que establecimos hasta el 100% que es donde termina el efecto que estamos buscando
- Con `animation-timing-function` vamos a indicar el comportamiento de la animación

Ejemplo

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo1</title>
      <style>
        #circulo {
            background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%, white 1px, aqua 3%, darkblue 60%, aqua 100%);  
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation-name: rotate1;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }
        @keyframes rotate1 {
          0%{
            transform: rotate( 0deg);
          }
          100%{
            transform: rotate(360deg);
          }
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="circulo"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Importante**

> Si no deseas que la animación sea permanente, entonces alcanza con quitar la propiedad y valor: **`animation-iteration-count: infinite;`**

**Referencias**

- [animation CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function)
- [animation CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations)